# Global Resources in Text propery

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I have a problem when I want to change the language of my website. I use Global Resources for this.
When I use the default language, it shows the right text. No problems then.

But when I change the Culture, then it does not update the text in ASP.NET Control properties.
I have no idea why.

This code works perfect

```
<h1><%= Resources.Default.Register %></h1>
```

But this code unfortunatly doesn't change its language

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Default, Register %>" />
```

I change the language by clicking on a LinkButton, like this

```
protected void lbNL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");

            Page.Culture = "nl-BE";
            Page.UICulture = "nl-BE";

        }
```

Can you please help me

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I change my language from English (default) to French.

```
<h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWelcome" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Welcome %>" /></h3>
```

I'm forced to use a control such as an asp:Label or an asp:Literal.

Also my global resource file is in App_GlobalResources folder and is called **Resource.fr.resx**.  Welcome is the name of the key in the resource file.

Also, when I change my culture info to french I am just using the two letter code **fr**

** * ** ** *  EDIT * * * * * * * * *

This may be your problem.  You may need to override InitializeCulture.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Comment: My code is like this, but unfortunately it doesn't change the language when I click on a button.

Comment: When a page is being run and ASP.NET is retrieving values from the resource manager, ASP.NET selects the version of the resource file that most closely matches the current UICulture setting for the page or uses resource fallback to obtain a resource. For example, if you are running the Default.aspx page and the current UICulture property is set to es (Spanish), ASP.NET uses the compiled version of the local resource file Default.aspx.es.resx.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427(v=vs.85).aspx